# Using .NET authentication and views

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, .net-3.5

I am using the .NET Authentication for Windows forms (not MVC) in .NET 3.5.  I used the drag and drop toolbar to add in asp:Login but how do I customize this? Is there another tool to use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you can use **Design** window to customize the layout.

[image]